# Send cursor to the end of input value in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am dynamically passing a value to my input field when clicking delete (in order to edit the last input entry).

I can see that in Chrome once the input value gets rendered the cursor shows up a the beginning of the word, while in Safari and Firefox goes at the end of the value but the last letter gets deleted.

How can I always see the cursor at the end without deleting the last letter(unless I hit backspace twice)?

```
  tagEvent(e) {
    const tag = this.text.value;
    const tagGroup = tag.split(" ");
    const tiles = this.props.tiles;
    const hasTiles = Object.keys(tiles).length > 0;

    if(e.keyCode === 32 || e.keyCode === 13){
      e.preventDefault();
      tagGroup.map(tag => this.props.addTile(tag));
      this.tagForm.reset();
    }

    if(e.keyCode === 8 && hasTiles && tag === '' ) {
      this.props.editLastTile();
      this.tagForm.reset();
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="input-wrapper">
        <form ref={(input) => this.tagForm = input}>
          <input ref={(input) => this.text = input}
                 type="text"
                 name="new-item"
                 placeholder="type and press space"
                 autoComplete="off"
                 defaultValue={this.props.value}
                 onKeyDown={(e) => this.tagEvent(e)} />
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
```

[Here a Pen with the full code](https://codepen.io/fabioioio/pen/mmZZVo)

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can explicitly set cursor position, to do so add this to `Input`:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (prevProps.value !== this.props.value) {
        this.text.selectionStart = this.text.value.length;
        this.text.selectionEnd = this.text.value.length;
    }
}
```

To prevent removing last character add a `e.preventDefault()` after `if(e.keyCode === 8 && hasTiles && tag === '' ) {`

Edited [Pen](https://codepen.io/sassanh/pen/yXRLQx)

Answer (score 26):

Another simple solution:

```
<input ref={ref => ref && ref.focus()}
    onFocus={(e)=>e.currentTarget.setSelectionRange(e.currentTarget.value.length, e.currentTarget.value.length)}
    />
```

`ref` triggers focus, and that triggers `onFocus` to calculate the end and set the cursor accordingly.

Comment: this worked well for me as I needed to pass this functionality in props to a grandchild input

Comment: I don't get this onFocus trick, this will also move the cursor to the end if user clicks on the input right?

Answer (score 13):

For those of you coming here trying to use this with react hooks

A simple texfield component that toggles the type of the input to password/text, this is the typical case where you would like to allow users to see their password by clicking on a button to toggle the type and see the value.

```
function TextField() {
  const [type, setType] = useState('text');
  const inputRef = useRef(null);
  const onToggle = useCallback(() => {
    setType(current => type === 'text' ? 'password' : 'text');
    // Setting focus here
    inputRef.current.focus();
  }, []);
  useEffect(() => {
    // Moving cursor to the end
    inputRef.current.selectionStart = inputRef.current.value.length;
    inputRef.current.selectionEnd = inputRef.current.value.length;
  }, [type]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        ref={inputRef}
        type={type}
       />
       <button onClick={onToggle}>toggle type</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer.
Following the documentation of MDN this can also be done with the method [`setSelectionRange`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange) that sets both `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd`, as in:

.

```inputRef.current.setSelectionRange(selectionStart, selectionEnd)
```

Comment: Tried a few different methods from different related questions/answers, this one using useRef & useEffect was the only one that worked for me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A very simple hack that worked for me is - setting the value on focus.

Example

```
const [val, setVal] = useState();
...
<input 
  val={val} 
  onFocus={
    ()=>{
      setVal(val + " "); 
      setTimeout(() => setVal(val.slice(0, val.length-1), 0);
    }
 ...
/>
```